# Jedi Library and Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, c++builder, jedi, delphi-xe, c++builder-xe

Typically, the install of the JEDI libraries is done using the installer.   Does anybody know if the installer

1. Works with Rad Studio XE (Delphi and Builder)
2. Can be easily modified to do so if not
3. Knows of some manual install instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current state of the JCL and JVCL do not work with Builder C++ XE.

The author has stated he hopes for a release On Sept 10, 2010

Comment: A release is now available on the JEDI site.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what JEDI Libraries your talking about as there are several.

Typically updated JEDI Library are available for download on sourceforge a few days after release.   As they are not permitted to publish the required changes before the release.  But since the JCL is used in the RAD Studio IDE, it is always updated to the latest version.

The JCL (JEDI Code Library) is on the partner DVD.

JCL for XE can be downloaded from Code Central here: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27879

The JVCL (Jedi Visual component Library) can be downloaded from Code Central here: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27901

Comment: If they can't publish changes before the Delphi release, then where do they check in their XE-related changes in the meantime? Or is it just the *binaries* that they can't publish in advance?

Comment: Either in a separate repository or in a branch with limited access.

Comment: The JEDI libraries on the partner DVD do not work with C++Builder XE

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi XE Partner DVD contains JCL and JVCL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Delphi XE trial, then it's possible that jedi installer does not work even when Jedi make the release with support of Delphi XE. That is because the tral version of the products doesn't support command line tools (e.g. command line compiler) that the installers need to compile Jedi's BPLs

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are in a hurry you should wait for an official release, but if there are not "breaking changes" (and AFAIK XE has not), it's not difficult to modify the packages to generate different bpl/dcp names at least and install them manually.